# mysqladmin won't accept password

Tags: mysql, osx-yosemite

I have a new MBP with Yosemite. I have installed the latest version of MySQL (5.6.21 via the pkg file) and have successfully set up its password and see it through Sequel Pro. However, I cannot login to mysqladmin. Normally, like with Ubuntu, I can do:

```
 mysqladmin -u root -p
```

But terminal dumps me to the helpful help file. Of course, the rules haven't changed. The help file confirms that if I leave off the password after the -p argument that the TTY will take over but it does not.

```
 mysqladmin -u root --password
```

yields the same help message.

```
 mysqladmin -u root -password 'password'
```

asks for a password expected BUT when I pass it then yields unknown command 'password'.

I did do the /usr/local/bin/mysql_secure_installation script but didn't change any values. If my root password has changed why would I still be able to connect via sequel pro and other PHP connections?

I'm sure it's something I'm overlooking but appreciate is there's something I've not found in my Google searches, thanx, sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program [mysqladmin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqladmin.html) is not an interactive client. It is a client-based utility. mysqladmin allows you run connect to mysqld, run a single command from a specific set of commands, and then, disconnect.

## EXAMPLE #1

Some commands that can be done in the [mysql client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html) can be done in mysqladmin.

```
mysqladmin -uroot -ppassword flush-hosts
mysqladmin -uroot -ppassword processlist
```

## EXAMPLE #2

Some commands that cannot be done in the [mysql client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html) can be done in mysqladmin.

For instance, an orderly shutdown of mysqld can be done like this:

```
mysqladmin -uroot -ppassword shutdown
```

Of course, `service mysql stop` will work as well. Unfortunately, `service mysql stop` does not work when the socket file is gone. This can sometimes happen when a person issues `service mysql start` with mysqld already running. That deletes the socket file. Running `mysqladmin -uroot -ppassword shutdown` requires the socket file because you are connecting as `root@localhost`. If you have the user `root@127.0.0.1` defined, you can still issue an orderly shutdown by connecting via TCP/IP with mysqladmin like this

```
mysqladmin -uroot -ppassword -h127.0.0.1 --protocol=tcp shutdown
```

I have many posts about this such as these

- `Mar 06, 2013` : [How to properly kill MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36082/877)
- `May 08, 2012` : [How to properly stop MySQL server on Mac OS X?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/17602/877)

With regard to your original quesiton, if you want to test the password, you should be using [***mysql***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html), not mysqladmin. You should do this

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

As an alternative, if you still want to use [mysqladmin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqladmin.html), do this

```
mysqladmin -uroot -ppassword ping
```

## Give it a Try !!!